# Java Netbeans System Using Biometric

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

Our group we're asked to develop a system that used a biometric. Please, if anyone knows any site already do the system we aim to do that using NetBeans as our platform.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [NetBeans Platform showcases](https://platform.netbeans.org/screenshots.html)? Maybe there is some application that might look interesting to you.

Otherwise Geertjan seems to did [some work with a fingerprint reader](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/fingerprint_reader_on_the_netbeans%20%22some%20work%20with%20a%20fingerprint%20reader) as a NetBeans Plugin, maybe this might help.

Otherwise you should get a bit more specific what you mean by "biometric" and what kind of stuff you would like to plugin in the NetBeans Platform. Generally as soon as you have a Java lib for whatever you want to do, you can use the NetBeans Platform.

Comment: I tried to redirect to the link you gave but it can't found

Comment: Sir, please help me how can I display the finger has been scanned using our bio metrics in java netbeans.